# Find shortest triangle in a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx

I have a set of points and need to select an optimal subset of 3 of them, where the criterion is a linear sum of some properties of the points, and some properties of pairs of the points.

In Python, this is quite easy using `itertools.combinations`:

```py
all_points = combinations(points, 3)
costs = []
for i, (p1, p2, p3) in enumerate(all_points):
    costs.append((p1.weight + p2.weight + p3.weight
                  + pair_weight(p1, p2) + pair_weight(p1, p3) + pair_weight(p2, p3),
                 i))
costs.sort()
best = all_points[costs[0][1]]
```

The problem is that this is a brute force solution, requiring to enumerate all possible combinations of 3 points, which is O(n^3) in the number of points and therefore easily leads to a very large number of evaluations to perform.  I have been trying to research whether there is a more efficient way to do this, perhaps taking advantage of the linearity of the cost function.

I have tried turning this into a `networkx` graph featuring node and edge weights.  However, I have not yet found an algorithm in that toolkit that can calculate the "shortest triangle", particularly one that considers both edge and node weights.  (Shortest path algorithms tend to only consider edge weights for example.)

There are functions to enumerate all cliques, and then I can select 3-cliques, and calculate the cost, but this is also brute force and therefore not better than doing it with `combinations` as above.

Are there any other algorithms I can look at?

By the way, if I do not have the edge weights, it is easy to just sort the nodes by their node-weight and choose the first three.  So it is really the paired costs that add complexity to this problem.  I am wondering if somehow I can just list all pairs and find the top-k of those that form triangles, or something better?  At least if I could efficiently enumerate top candidates and stop the enumeration on some heuristic, it might be better than the brute force approach.

Comment: "factorial in the number of points". The complexity would be `O(N^3)`

Comment: you are right, the factorials cancel out.  i have adjusted the question.

Comment: Maybe since you have a set of points, do a delanuey trianglulation. Could that maybe help the complexity?

Comment: Do you really have a faster way to solve this if there are only edge weights? You can easily get rid of node weights by adding half the weight of each node to all edges incident to it, and setting all node weights to 0. This preserves your original sum and gives an 'only edge weights' problem.

Comment: thank you for that suggestion about splitting the node weights into edge weights, it is a good idea.  perhaps then some smallest k-clique algorithm could help, although i do not find such an algorithm unfortunately.  (some wikipedia search reveals to me that finding k-cliques may be a brute force algorithm at best, so maybe there is nothing better.)

Comment: i have been playing with making a list of all edge weights (O(n^2)), sorting that, and seeing if i can find the first other node that shares two edges within the top k edges.  but it is complicated and i am not sure this is the best cost triplet.  interesting though.  it does seem to reduce the candidates that are needed to be evaluated.

Comment: Is your graph directed or undirected? Are the weights integers? How large is the range of weights? Are weights always positive? Whether a subcubic algorithm is known [depends on the answer to those questions](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3186893)

Comment: interesting, thanks i'll read that closely.  quick answers: weights are not integers, and can be negative.  (node weights are positive, edge weights are negative.. trying to find an optimum between these two criteria really, maximizing one and minimizing the other).  as for size, there is technically no limit, but in my case the node weights are distances in meters and are about 10 m at maximum, and the edge weights are angular differences.  So in practice they are limited.  I am trying to choose 3 points that minimize a distance to something, and maximize differences between their angles.

Comment: i should also note that i am ok with an approximate solution, which takes this a bit outside of typical literature i guess.  i want a statistically best solution over my dataset, but if the solution is only approximate in exchange for much better runtime then it is acceptable in my case. hence thinking about heuristics and top-k approaches.

Comment: It sounds like you really have a geometry problem, and so you'll probably have much better luck if you explain the geometry of it.  Reducing problems to their most general form is an effective way to make them a lot more difficult to solve.

Comment: For example, the vague characterization "minimizing distance to an origin while maximizing angles between points" suggests to me that the first step will probably be to sort the points according to their angle from the origin... which of course has no meaning at all in your generic version of the problem.

Comment: @JosipJuros: this is random advice. You don't even know if the problem is 2D, and there is no notion of a distance metric.

Comment: Must every triple be considered ?

Comment: The problem can be slightly simplified, because you can absorb the vertex weights in the edge weights and you only have to consider the latter.

Comment: About the weights on the edges: are they arbitrary, or do they correspond to geometry? If they correspond to geometry, there is probably a very fast algorithm to solve your problem, as identifying "close points" in the plane or in 3d space is a well-known and relatively easy problem. If the weights on the vertices and edges are completely arbitrary, then your problem is a quadratic assignment problem, which is a more general problem and thus has less efficients algorithms than the geometry problem. It's still a well-known problem with affordable algorithms, though :)

Answer (score 1):

From now on, I will use `n` as the number of nodes and `m` as the number of edges. If your graph is fully connected, then `m` is just `n` choose 2. I'll also disregard node weights, because as the comments to your initial post have noted, the node weights can be absorbed into the edges they're connected to.

Your algorithm is `O(n^3)`; it's hopefully not too hard to see why: You iterate over every possible triplet of nodes. However, it is possible to iterate over every triangle in a graph in `O(m sqrt(m))`:

```
for every node u:
    for every node v adjacent to u:
        if degree(u) < degree(v): continue;
        for every node w adjacent to v:
            if degree(v) < degree(w): continue;
            if u is not connected to w: continue;
            // <u,v,w> is a triangle!
```

The proof for this algorithm's runtime of `O(m sqrt(m))` is nontrivial, so I'll direct you here: [https://cs.stanford.edu/~rishig/courses/ref/l1.pdf](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Erishig/courses/ref/l1.pdf)

If your graph is fully connected, then you've gotta stick with the `O(n^3)`, I think. There might be some early-pruning ideas you can do but they won't lead to a significant speedup, probably 2x at very best.